# Using vlookup and count in the same formula

Tags: excel, count, vlookup

I am having difficulties combining Vlookup value with count.

As you can see here, CPR is a unique code for every employee and next to it is the type of mistakes that specific employee did.

[image]

In this sheet, i want to count the number of mistakes done by that specific employee from the first sheet which mean the code should only count the cells that only contain value.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$10=E2)*NOT(ISBLANK($B$1:$B$10)))
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your code and it worked in the same sheet only but in my case, i am using a different sheet to retrieve a value and that does not work for me. `=SUMPRODUCT((Jan!$G$4=$D$4)*NOT(ISBLANK(Jan!$H$4)))`

Comment: i discovered that this code is not working with the drop down list (type of mistakes). Any idea how to prevent that ?

Comment: You must specify an ranges for sum e.g. ```=SUMPRODUCT((Jan!$G$4:$G$100=$D$4)*NOT(ISBLANK(Jan!$H$4:$H$100))). ``` What exactly is the problem with drop down?

Comment: you are right i thought i cannot retrieve value from drop down list but it was just me not specify the range like you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much my problem has been solved thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use Excel's `countif` function.  I don't think `vlookup` is helpful here.

For example, if you write `=countif(G4:G999, 8345)` it will count how many times the number 8345 occurs in that range of cells.

Comment: True, but i want the countif function to count how many mistakes under a specific CPR number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`=COUNTIF(Jan!G:G,Sheet13!D1)`

The above formula count how many times the value in `Sheet13!D1` appears in `Jan!G:G`

Comment: It will only count how many CPR number is there. But, I want to count how many mistakes is under a specific CPR number because the total number of mistakes is different than the total number of CPR

Comment: it turned out that the code is working but it does not retrieve data from list cell